# Want to show label 'Wait, reading data.....' in client after dropdownlist selection ASP NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client, postback

I have an ASP NET page with a dropdownlist. When the user select an item, a postback occurs, but it takes some time to receive the response, due to server processing. I want to show a label 'wait, reading data' or something, on the client side while waiting for the response.
Have tried some samples but nothing, any help?

this, does not work

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ShowConfirm(obj) {
        document.getElementById("<%=Lbl_Buscar.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
        __doPostBack(obj.id, '');
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can do this very easy with a button click, or in your case a dropdown.

The simple trick is that a button click, or even a dropdown can have BOTH a client side event, and the server side event.

This works for a button, or in this case a drop down.

so say this markup:

```
<div style="float:left;margin-top:18px">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboHotels" runat="server"
        Width="200px"
        AutoPostBack="True"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="LBHotels_SelectedIndexChanged"
        DataValueField="City"
        DataTextField="City"
        onchange="cbowait()">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<div id="mywait" style="float:left;margin-left:25px;display: none">
    <img src="../Content/wait2.gif" style="height: 62px; width: 75px" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please wait..." 
        Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
</div>
<script>
    function cbowait() {
        $('#mywait').show()
    }
</script>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    CssClass="table table-hover" Width="35%">

</asp:GridView>
```

We have a dropdown list (combo box), then a "div" with text, picture (animated gif), or whatever for the please wait message.

but, note how we have both a client side, and server side event for the drop down list.

So, code behind is really simple. (since the post-back WHEN complete will re-load the page - and thus re-hide our message).

So, code behind is this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // load up our combo box
        string strSQL =
            "select City from City order by City";
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        cboHotels.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        cboHotels.DataBind();
        cboHotels.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select hotel", ""));

    }

}

DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
    {
        cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}


protected void LBHotels_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strSQL = 
        @"SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, HotelName, Description
        FROM tblhotels WHERE City = @City";
    SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cboHotels.Text;
    GridView1.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
    GridView1.DataBind();

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // fake long delay
}
```

So, we "fake a 2 second delay

the result is thus this:

[image]

So, all you do is add a "div" with say a spinner and some text like "please wait...".

And note how ZERO changes was required to the server side (code behind) here.

I do this all the time for buttons, and the approach is just the same.

Eg this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"
        OnClick="Button1_Click"
        OnClientClick="cbowait();return true;"
        />
```

note how for the button, we MUST return "true" for the server side event to run. (and this feature can be rather handy, since you can then launch a js "confirm" dialog, and if the user hits no then you return false, and the server side button click does not run. Great for say a delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your detailed response. The solution isnt working for me, after select the item in the dropdown, the page does not postback, not even display the mesage. I think it is because is inside a panel with a modalpopup extender. In fact, for the dropdown to work, I have to remove the onchange part.

```
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnShowPopUp4" runat="server" Text="Button" style="display:none" />
                    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderNC" runat="server" 
                            BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                            DropShadow="True" 
                            PopupControlID="PanelNC" TargetControlID="BtnShowPopUp4"  CancelControlID="BtnCancelNC" >
                    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>   
                    <asp:Panel defaultbutton="BtnOkNC" ID="PanelNC" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" 
                        Width="585px"  >
                        <span style="text-decoration: underline; font-size: large">SOLICITUD NOTA DE CREDITO</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                        &nbsp;<table style="width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 122px; text-align: left; ">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="Rdr_USNC" runat="server" GroupName="Moneda" Text="US$" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="Rdr_USNC_CheckedChanged" />
                                    <asp:RadioButton ID="Rdr_RDNC" runat="server" GroupName="Moneda" Text="RD$" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="Rdr_USNC_CheckedChanged" />
                                    &nbsp;
                                    <div id="mywait" style="display: none">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Buscar" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700; color: #CC0000" Text="**Buscando Datos" ></asp:Label>
                                   </div>
                                    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 122px; text-align: left; background-color: #74D1A3;"><b>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small" Text="Cliente"></asp:Label>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:HyperLink ID="Hyp_Cod_Cliente" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" style="font-size: small"></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </b></td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Cb_Clientes" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="DS_Clientes" DataTextField="wNombre" 
                                        DataValueField="Codigo" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt" Height="25px"  Width="350px"
                                         OnSelectedIndexChanged="Cb_Clientes_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="cbowait()"  >
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        function cbowait() {
                                            $('#mywait').show()
                                        }
                                    </script>           
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```